# POP3 Login restriction error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3, outlook.com

I know this question may not adhere to this website's standards but I couldn't find the answer anywhere else .
I'm trying to create mail listener client which checks a POP3 account every 30 seconds for any new mails and downloads it. Right now I'm testing it out on Outlook.com. The issue I face is, after say 3 -4 tries , it gives me an error saying `LOGIN Limit reached. Try logging in fewer times in every 15 minutes`.

This seems to be a login restriction imposed by Outlook.com but is there any way to overcome it ? I mean practically , I'm just logging in and not closing the connection so Its still logged in .So there's no reason why it should be giving me the error. I'm not in a position to post any codes for various reasons.  The best I can do is give you an algorithm of what I'm doing:

```
1. Open connection for a user
2. Open inbox folder of that user
3. Read mails 
4. Close inbox folder
5. Sleep for 30 seconds
6. Goto step 2
```

Only on app exit, I close the connection.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong in the steps assuming that the code is correct.

Comment: i suspect that every time you check for mail, it sends the auth token.  Most mail clients have a minimum time of 60 seconds.  I recommend trying that if it is an option.  Alternatively, close the connection when you are done with it - although this may not be preferable if you are checking every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

If there was a way to bypass the server-imposed limit, there would really be no point in having that limit, would there?  :-)

Note that you **are** closing the connection when you close the Inbox.  Because the POP3 protocol only allows you to access one folder, when you close the Inbox the JavaMail POP3 provider just remembers that you were able to connect to the server and the next time you open the Inbox it reconnects to the server using the same username/password.  The Store appears to be "open", but there's no active connection.

So, bottom line, you need to open the Inbox less frequently.